# $K$-affine $Hom$ functor relating to Polynomial Maps (Exercise in _Algebra: Chapter 0_ by Aluffi)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory, category-theory

I'm currently learning some category theory and algebraic geometry, the basics at least. In *Algebra: Chapter 0* by Aluffi, there is an exercise describing the relationship between morphisms of affine varieties and "polynomial maps" (not yet defined in this chapter). It starts with describing a functor $\mathcal{H}_{S} = Hom_{K\text{-}Aff}(*, S)$ for an affine $K$-variety $S$ ($K$ algebraically closed) such that $\mathcal{H}_{S}(\mathbb{A}^{0}_{K}) \cong S$. This was clear.

The second part of the exercise is to show that any $\varphi \in Hom_{K\text{-}Aff}(S, T)$ determines a map of sets $S \rightarrow T$. I have a feeling this has to do with the previously defined functor, but I'm not sure. Otherwise, would it simply be a map of the underlying sets of $S$ and $T$? I believe that $Hom_{K\text{-}Aff}(S, T) = Hom_{K\text{-}}(K[T], K[S])$ by equivalence of categories $K\text{-}Aff \approx K\text{-}Alg$, where $K\text{-}Alg$ is the category of finitely reduced $K$-algebras. Thus $\varphi$ is really a $K$-algebra morphism $K[T] \rightarrow K[S]$. But even this is not explicitly defined.

The exercise goes on to have the reader show that if $S \subseteq \mathbb{A}^{m}$ and $T \subseteq \mathbb{A}^{n}$, the previously defined set-map $S \rightarrow T$ is the restriction of a "polynomial function" $\mathbb{A}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^{n}$. I know vaguely what a polynomial function is (a sort of coordinate mapping $(f_{1}, \ldots, f_{n}): S \rightarrow T$, where the $f_{i}$ are elements of $K[S]$), but Im not sure how these exercises connect to each other. I guess that we could construct $S \rightarrow T$ via $(f_{1}, \ldots, f_{n})$, which definitely gives a mapping of sets. But the only map $\mathbb{A}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^{n}$ that I could think of which corresponds to a polynomial function is $K[T] \rightarrow K[S]; f \mapsto f \circ (f_{1}, \ldots, f_{n})$, which is "equivalent" categorically to the mapping $(f_{1}, \ldots, f_{n}): (a_{1}, \ldots, a_{m}) \mapsto (f_{1}(a_{1}, \ldots, a_{m}), \ldots, f_{n}(a_{1}, \ldots, a_{m}))$.

This is from the definition of polynomial map from Wikipedia, but I know that I'm supposed to define this myself through this exercise. I'm a little lost, so any hints or insight would be appreciated.